# can't load database in dhtmlxgantt php

Tags: javascript, php

I have problem with my project,data in database can't show in ganttchart dhtmlx

this my code in data.php

```
<?php

   include ('../../codebase/connector/gantt_connector.php');

   $res=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("gantt");

   $gantt = new JSONGanttConnector($res);
   //$gantt->render_links("gantt_links","id","source",target,type");
   $gantt->render_table(
   "schedule",
   "id",matrl,"cust_name","po_num",
   "start_date,duration"
  );
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using strange set of parameters for render_table
It must be render_table(table, id, fields)

```
$gantt->render_table(
 /*table*/  "schedule",
 /*id*/     "id",
 /*fields*/ "start_date,duration,matrl,cust_name,po_num"
);
```